# How to get a UIView aligned with the underlying UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented a scrollview on top of a UIView.  I then placed another UIView on top of that.  I am noticing that the scrollview covers the navigation bar, but the UIView i placed ontop of the scrollview it does not. I set the scrollview and the UIView on top of it to be of the same height  Therefore when i place an view object (Label: 'footer') at the bottom of the top UIView I cannot see it. How do I adjust the height of the top UIView accordingly?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the specific view in the view controller scene. Click on size inspector menu in the utility area. Playround with the views and constraints as you need. 
[image]

Comment: is there a way of getting a dynamic scrollview? At the moment I am setting the height to about 1200.  But if I do not use all this verticle space it is still there and so looks a bit not so great

Comment: Scrollview height is usually determined by the height of its content when there are no fixed constraints added to the superview. Set the vertical hugging priority to 1000 or maximum and set the bottom constraint less than 1000. Which will dynamically adjust the size of scrollview if the content in the scrollview is smaller than the screen size you see no scroll bar.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by bottom constraint.  ?

Comment: I meant any of the vertical constraint(top or bottom )for the scroll view. If you want scrollview to be at the bottom. The top priority must be less than the hugging priority and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

By Following This steps may resolve your issue ( i am showing screenshot along with constraint added ) :-

**Step 1:** - Select ViewController and Uncheck **Adjust Scroll View insets**

[image]

**Step 2:** - Select **ScrollView and Set this constraint** : (Screenshots added)

[image]

**Step 3:** Finally Select `UIView` added inside `ScrollView` -

[image]

**Step 4** : Final Constraint .

[image]

As you have already set constraint , so i think just checking it solve your issue . Feel free to share your feedback on this.